# Docker Compose with one Terminating Container

Tags: docker, exit, exit-code, docker-compose, fig

I'm having a docker compose setup of a database container, an application container and one container which pre-loads the database with necessary data.

I want to start all of the containers together with `docker-compose up` while the pre-loading container terminates after it has completed it work with `exit 0`.

But terminating this one container takes down the complete setup with the message:

```
composesetup_load_1 exited with code 0
Gracefully stopping... (press Ctrl+C again to force)
Stopping composesetup_app_1...
Stopping composesetup_db_1...
```

Is there any way of having multiple containers with different life-time in one docker-compose setup? If yes, how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My workaround for now is to keep the pre-loading container running by adding `tail -f /dev/null` to the end of the entrypoint script. This keeps the process running, while nothing actual happens.

Comment: Is this a common method of doing this sort of thing? Is there a "right" / "official" way to do this? I love this slick solution, in either case.

Comment: This, so much. Thanks

Comment: Clever, but it'd be better to `sleep inf`

Answer (score -1):

Using [`-d` option](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/) at `docker-compose up -d` will run the process in detached mode. This avoids the need to kill the service with Ctrl+C and therefore stop the containers.

Note: I am asumming you killed the process with Ctrl+C from the message "`Gracefully stopping... (press Ctrl+C again to force)`" you shared.

Comment: No, I've not terminated the process with Ctrl+C the process has just completed its work and thus terminates with `exit 0`. So running docker-compose with the `-d` option is no solution.

Comment: @white_gecko, ok, thanks for clarifying. The behaviour is then as if the flag `--abort-on-container-exit` was set?

Comment: Ok, maybe this flag is a solution … when I've posted the question at least this behavior was default.